# An Example of Markov chain

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, statistical-inference

A Markov chain $Q = \{ Q_0, Q_1, \ldots\}$ with state space and transition matrix as $U = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and

W = \begin{bmatrix}
.2 & .3 & .3 & .2\\
.4 & .2 & .3 & .1\\
.1 & .1 & .7 & .1\\
.4 & .2 & .1 & .3
\end{bmatrix} .
respectively. Find

$P\{Q_1 = 3, Q_2=2, Q_3 = 1, Q_4 =2, Q_5 = 2| Q_0 = 4\}$

What I did so far:

It's known that the Markov chain property is such that $P\{X_{n+1} = j| X_{0} = i_0, \ldots, X_{n+1}, X_n = 1 \} = P\{X_{n+1} = j | X_n =i \}$. So, I thought of using the property to solve the problem like this

$P\{Q_1 = 3| Q_0 = 4\} = p_{43} = 0.1$

Because the conditioned MC variable is $Q_0$, then, $P\{X_{n+1} = j | X_n =i \} = P\{Q_1 = 3| Q_0 = 4\}$ but I am not sure whether my approach approach is right. Similarly, $P\{ Q_3 = 3, Q_4 =1, Q_5 = 3| Q_2 = 1\} = P\{Q_3 = 3| Q_2 = 1\} = p_{13} = 0.3$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: @saulspatz. I am getting ready to post what I was able to do. Thank you for letting me know

Comment: @saulspatz. I've updated the question for about 24hours and the question is still closed. Is there something I have to do again?

Comment: It's just been reopened.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the right thing.
$$P(Q_1 = 3, Q_2=2, Q_3 = 1, Q_4 =2, Q_5 = 2| Q_0 = 4)=p_{43}p_{32}p_{21}p_{12}p_{22}$$

However, your notation is incorrect.  You don't meant to say $$P(Q_3 = 3, Q_4 =1, Q_5 = 3| Q_2 = 1) = P(Q_3 = 3| Q_2 = 1) = p_{13}$$  $p_{13}$ is just the first step in the calculation.  The correct equation would be
$$P(Q_3 = 3, Q_4 =1, Q_5 = 3| Q_2 = 1) =\\ P(Q_3 = 3| Q_2 = 1)P(Q_4=1,Q_5=3|Q_3=3)$$

Comment: From where you ended, is it true to say $P(Q_3 = 3|Q_2=1)P(Q_4 = 1, Q_5 = 3|Q_3 = 3) = p_{13}p_{31}p_{13} ?$ If yes, how is $P(Q_4 = 1, Q_5 = 3|Q_3 = 3)  = p_{31}p_{13} ?$

Comment: @Ab2020 Yes.  Since it's a Markov chain, the probability of transition to a given state depends only on the state the chain is in, so any sequence of transitions can broken up into one-step transitions like this.